# Global filters PrimeNG Angular2

Tags: angular, primeng

How to apply multiple global filters in primeng angular2 like one input, dropdown and date range in global filters?
How to add for others like dropdown and date range.
For input we can use like:

```
<div>
    <input #gb type="text" placeholder="Global search">
</div>
<p-dataTable [value]="workOrders" [globalFilter]="gb">`
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to implement date range filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Global filter is just for containing searches.You can take a look at this filter section

http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter

If you use it this way you should add component information to the app.module.ts according to your usage.

Comment: Actually i have requirement that on the basis of some date range and dropdown value(which are global) ,list got filtered then user can use column filtering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want filtering based on multiple inputs then you need to implement the filter logic yourself. On the value change event of any control you can call a function in the .ts file and within that function you can filter the data source of your table.
For example, I have a bunch of list boxes (one per column) that appear on a side panel to display an amazon style filtering of my data table. The code looks like this -

```
<p-accordion [multiple]="true" *ngFor="let col of filterColumns; let i=index" >
            <p-accordionTab header="{{col.display}}"  [selected]="showAllFilters">
                <p-listbox  [style]="{'width':'180px'}" [options]="col.values" [(ngModel)]="this['Selected' + col.display]" multiple="multiple" checkbox="checkbox" filter="filter" (onChange) = "advancedFilterChange(this['Selected' + col.display],col.column,'in')"></p-listbox>
            </p-accordionTab>                         
        </p-accordion>
```

The code behind looks like this -

```
    private advancedFilterChange(values:string[],col:string,matchMode:string):void{

      this.programTable.filter(values,col,matchMode);

 }
```

Where programTable is a reference to the primeng data table in your html which you can access by using viewchild

```
@ViewChild('dtPrograms') programTable:DataTable;
```

Hope this helps...